# How do I modify this query to search for specific tags?

Tags: support, tags, search, data-explorer, sql

I am forking [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1064843/time-to-answer-first-answer-last-answer-accepted-answer-highest-scored-answer#resultSets) query, which essentially outputs the time between the question being asked and the answer being given. However, I am trying to modify the query to only search for [java](/questions/tagged/java). I tried this:

```
WITH
    Answers AS (
        SELECT *
            FROM Posts as P
              INNER JOIN Tags
              ON Tags.Id = P.TagId
            WHERE PostTypeId = 2 -- Answers
            AND Tags.TagName = 'java'

    )
...
```

But it clearly does not work. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: [Cross posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589386/how-do-i-modify-this-query-to-search-for-specific-tags).

Answer (score 5):

Answers don't have tags, Questions have.

Joining with PostTags on the Posts.ParentId should do the trick for that snippet:

```
WITH
    Answers AS (
        SELECT *
            FROM Posts as P
              INNER JOIN PostTags pt       -- posttags is the join table
                 ON pt.postid = p.parentid -- join the question
              INNER JOIN Tags
                 ON Tags.Id = pt.TagId     -- join with posttags
            WHERE PostTypeId = 2 -- Answers
            AND Tags.TagName = 'java'

    )
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Tags` field looks like this: `<java><unicode><comments>` so you need to use [`LIKE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). [Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1064923/time-to-answer-first-answer-last-answer-accepted-answer-highest-scored-answer?NumberOfQuestions=100) how I did it (matching on the questions' tags):

```sql
WHERE
    Questions.PostTypeId = 1 -- Questions
    AND Questions.Tags LIKE '%<java>%' -- Line I added
    AND year(Questions.CreationDate) between '2014' AND '2018'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a *like* query as well as a *contains* query in SQL...

As an *example*,

**Where Column_Name like '%Column_value%'**

else

**Where Contains(Column_Name, 'Column_Value')**